# How to combine numbers in different columns using matlab

Tags: matlab

excel has an equation or function to combine number in different column, as you can see in the picture below. having the same data in matlab , how can i combine numbers in a different columns.

having a d data:

```
a   b   c   d
1   1   1   3
2   1   0   5
1   2   5   30
3   4   1   26
-1  1   1   3
```

[image]

since 111 and -111 have the same values of d, so i combine it so that 1st cell in 1st column became 111,-111 and their d become 6 because i add it up, so can matlab do that? thanks

Comment: So what happens when you have two (or more) columns with a negative coefficient?  Say `a = -1, b = -2, c = 3`.  What happens when you combine these together in your `abc` format?

Comment: it became -1-23, which located in one cell

Comment: So you wish to have a cell array of strings all concatenated together based on the `d` column being the key?

Comment: yea you're right sir

Comment: Oh that's quite easy.  Give me a few minutes to write an answer.

Comment: @rayryeng, did you already write the code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[1 1 1 3;2 1 0 5; 1 2 5 30; 3 4 1 26; -1 1 1 3]

len=size(a);
x2=[]

for i=1:len(1)
s=num2str(a(i,1:len(2)-1));
s=s(s~=' ');
x2(i,:)=[str2num(s) (a(i,len(2)))];


end
```

Result:

```
x2 =

   111     3
   210     5
   125    30
   341    26
  -111     3
```

now to find the repeated indices:

```
u=unique(x2(:,2));
n=histc(x2(:,2),u);
ind=find(x2(:,2)==u(n>1))
```

Result:

```
ind =
     1
     5
```

Ok now to sum and combine:

```
xx=x2(ind,:)

ss=sum(xx(:,2));

s=num2str(xx(:,1)');
s=strrep(s, ' ', ',')

x2(min(ind),2) = ss;

x2(ind(ind~=min(ind)),:) = []

C = num2cell(x2);

C(min(ind),1) = cellstr(s)
```

The final result is:

```
C = 

'111,-111'    [ 6]
[     210]    [ 5]
[     125]    [30]
[     341]    [26]
```

Comment: what if i have m x n array? what is the general code for this? thanks

Comment: 111 and -111 didn't combine

Comment: I found the indices where the columm two from x2 combine, now you can sum and combine 111,-111

Comment: how can i do  that sir?

Comment: do you see my results ?

Comment: if there's a 0 in the first column for example a =0, b=2,c=1 it should be display as '021', but it appears '21' only, zero numbers disappear?

Comment: seems that you need do a homework, the code above solve the problem proposed in the question, we can not know the exceptions if you not told, the zero disappear after apply str2num function, try type 012 in the cli on matlab and you will see

Comment: so how to display "zero" numbers"?